# How can I send only last requst with Rx and Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I've got an EditText view and TextWatcher for it, in onTextChanged method I have to requst server for result with query from EditText field.
In my presenter I use rx for that, but i need to delay search until user's input ends. At this moment i've got this:

```
service.getData(query)
            .delaySubscription(REQUEST_DELAY_FROM_SERVER, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    data-> {
                        getViewState().showData(data);
                    },
                    error -> {
                        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), error.getMessage(), error);
                    }
            );
```

But delaySubscription does not work as desired. It collects all call and after delay sends every of them. I have to do same as if I had used handler.postDelayed(), when only once request will be send.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Edit 2:*

The saple of a presenter in **RxJava2**

```
class Presenter {
    private PublishSubject<String> queryPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    public Presenter() {
        queryPublishSubject
                .debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                // You might want to skip empty strings
                .filter(new Predicate<CharSequence>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean test(CharSequence charSequence) {
                        return charSequence.length() > 0;
                    }
                })
                // Switch to IO thread for network call and flatMap text input to API request
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap(new Function<CharSequence, Observable<...>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<...> apply(final CharSequence charSequence) {
                        return ...; // Call API
                    }
                })
                // Receive and process response on Main thread (if you need to update UI)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(...);
    }

    public void onSearchTextChanged(String query) {
        queryPublishSubject.onNext(query);
    }
}
```

*Edit 1:*

The same code in **RxJava 1**:

```
class Presenter {
    private PublishSubject<String> queryPublishSubject = PublishSubject.crate();

    public Presenter() {
        queryPublishSubject
            .debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            // You might want to skip empty strings
            .filter(new Func1<CharSequence, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(CharSequence charSequence) {
                    return charSequence.length() > 0;
                }
            })
            // Switch to IO thread for network call and flatMap text input to API request
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(new Func1<CharSequence, Observable<...>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<...> call(final CharSequence charSequence) {
                    return ... // Call API
                }
            })
            // Receive and process response on Main thread (if you need to update UI)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(...);
    }

    public void onSearchTextChanged(String query) {
        queryPublishSubject.onNext(query);
    } 
}
```

*Initial answer (with RxBinding and RxJava 1)*

The correct answer is to use `Debounce`, but besides that there are some other tricks you might find useful

```
textChangeListener = RxTextView
    .textChanges(queryEditText)
    // as far as I know, subscription to textChanges is allowed from Main thread only
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
    // On subscription Observable emits current text field value. You might not need that
    .skip(1) 
    .debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    // You might want to skip empty strings
    .filter(new Func1<CharSequence, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(CharSequence charSequence) {
            return charSequence.length() > 0;
        }
    })
    // Switch to IO thread for network call and flatMap text input to API request
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap(new Func1<CharSequence, Observable<...>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<...> call(final CharSequence charSequence) {
            return ... // Call API
        }
    })
    // Receive and process response on Main thread (if you need to update UI)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Comment: how can i implement this logic in my presenter class?

Comment: Where do you get `query` from?

Comment: I have Fragment implemted with TextWatcher. Simple EditText view and method 
    `@Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        presenter.onSearchTextChanged(String.valueOf(s));
    }` and presnter implements logic from topic

Comment: what exactly is Func1 because android studio can't find Func1 class although I included all needed rx dependencies

Comment: Hi! @AbdulmalekDery, I've updated the answer with RxJava 2 code sample. The initial answer was using RxJava 1. Hope this works

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar for an address research combining with RxAndroid could give something like that :

```
 RxTextView.textChanges(searchEditText)
                        .debounce(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .subscribe(....);
```

The [debounce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) operator will wait in this case that the observable stop to emit for 100ms before emitting the next value.

Comment: how can implement this in my presenter class? or it will only work with RxTextView?

Answer (score 0):

Try using debounce instead. For eg. code below look for changes in a TextView and do something when there is a change but with a debounce of 100 ms

```
RxTextView
.textChanges(queryEditText)
.debounce(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.doOnNext(new Action1<CharSequence>() {
    @Override
    public void call(CharSequence charSequence) {

    }
})
.subscribe();
```

Comment: That will work only if i've got RxTextView? can't i do same with just a method call? I need to try do this logic in my Presenter class. now it works like `@Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        presenter.onSearchTextChanged(String.valueOf(s));
    }` and presnter implements logic from topic

Comment: the way I've done is that in my view I've a method which returns return RxTextView.textChanges(queryEditText); so in the presenter, I am calling view.queryTextObservable().debounce().doOnNext().subscribe()